# How it will be charged if I dynamically launch and shutdown instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to programmatically launch and shutdown instances via `API`.

I know little about AWS , how is kind of action will be charged ?

if one instance costs for 10 dollar for one hour.

And I `launch`  and `shutdown` it  back and forth `10 times` in `1 hour`.

How will it be charged ?

Answer (score 1):

From [Stop and Start Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html)

**Each time you start a stopped instance** we charge a full instance hour, even if you make this transition multiple times within a single hour.

So in your example, you'll be charged $10 * 10 = $100

The correct terminology is **start** and **stop** the same instance. When you **launch**, you **create** a new instance, still the charge remains $100.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch and shutdown a single instance 10 times in one hour, you will be charged for 10 hours worth of time.

Amazon charges by the hour, rounded up to the nearest hour, by instance. Partial hours don't get combined with other partial hours.

You defintely don't want to start and stop instances over and over again if you can avoid it.